# No sound from computer HDMI port On RCA TV

Tags: audio, hdmi, tv, rca

So, I have a bit of a mystery, I have 2 Emachines EL1210-09s and a Acer AX3400G-U4802. The Emachines and Acer are pretty much identical. Both have AMD Athlon X2 processors. Both have Nvidia chip sets, but the Emachines have the 8200 and the Acer has the 9200. The Emachines came with Vista, and the Acer Windows 7

Now the issue I'm having is if I hook up the HDMI on the Emachine to pretty much any TV, I can get audio/video with no issue. If I hook them up to a RCA TV, I can get video but no audio. If I hook the Acer up to the RCA with HDMI, it outputs audio just fine.  Recently I reloaded one of the Emachines with windows 7 and still have the same issue. I called RCA support a while back and they were no help at all.

Any thoughts?  This is a complete mystery to me.

I'm including a picture, the acer on the right and emachine on the right

http://i17.photobucket.com/albums/b97/coderedz24/4F1D227D-EED1-4E95-BFB4-2D0172EC3A8D-1502-0000013106D3DFEF_zpsb9880d86.jpg

Comment: Check the nVidia Control Panel; make sure that "HDMI with audio" is enabled (rather than "HDMI w/o audio").  Make sure that the "HD audio" driver is installed (e.g. Realtek?) rather than the generic Microsoft driver.

Comment: Even though on one TV its fine and not another?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:  I had the incorrect Nvidia drivers, I went to the website and did the auto detect and it. I then downloaded the latest drivers they suggested and now my sound is working.